# Ищу аналог функции WebBrowser из WindowsForms (С#) в Intellij Idea, в Swing редакторе

Tags: java, c#, swing, webbrowser

Ищу аналог функции WebBrowser из WindowsForms (С#) в Intellij Idea (Java), в Swing редакторе, из предустановленных ничего нет, вот я думаю может есть какие-нибудь модуль расширения для этого, в частности мне нужно создать форму содержащее информацию из интернета. Ядро любое можно (не только IE6 как там ^_^), просто не могу найти подобного в сети, плохо ищу, может кто-нибудь посоветует?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

- [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) (на движке Chromium)
- Браузер из состава [DJProject](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html)

Comment: Платный вариант не катит, я тут пока только экспериментирую, хотя работает безотказно, а вот с DJProject вопрос

Внутри DJProject используются пакеты Eclipse которые отсутствуют в Intellij Idea, например... org.eclipse.swt.*, в частности из-за отсутствие данных библиотек у меня прога отказывается компилироваться, вот вопрос, где их мне взять?

Comment: Сам себе отвечу) http://www.eclipse.org/swt/, оттуда берется библиотека, после чего DJProject нормально работает)

Answer (score 3):

Тоже советую насчет [DJProject](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/), в отличие от JxBrowser, они бесплатны.

И легко вставляются в swing приложение:

```
JWerBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer().getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "start.html"));
webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Если будут проблемы с js - для таких случаев есть [Rhino.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino)

Comment: Внутри DJProject используются пакеты Eclipse которые отсутствуют в Intellij Idea, например... org.eclipse.swt.*, в частности из-за отсутствие данных библиотек у меня прога отказывается компилироваться, вот вопрос, где их мне взять?

Comment: Сам себе отвечу) http://www.eclipse.org/swt/, оттуда берется библиотека, после чего DJProject нормально работает)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, в JavaFX есть WebView. Вот [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/company/codeorchestra/blog/198776/) на хабр, где довольно подробно показаны примеры его использования. Входит в Java SE.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.